How to get application settings from Azure portal in Azure WebApplication
I have an Azure API that I host on Azure and publish through Visual Studio. I am trying to set values in the Azure portal application settings with the intent to have different values for the same key in different deployment slots. The settings are applied to both deployment slots.
The API is created with WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
I have tried retrieving the values with the following methods:

builder.Configuration["VariableName"];
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VariableName");
builder.Configuration.GetSection("Values").Get<Details>();

public class Details { public string VariableName { get; set; } }



I have tried adding the following code as suggested by other answers:

builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

The values I always retrieve are null no matter where in the Program.cs file I place the calls.
Interestingly, I can retrieve the values at a later time if I try to get them in a published API call. For example, I call CosmosDbConfig.initialize(builder.Configuration); early in Program.cs and assign values to the class such as apiKey = configuration["VariableName"]; However,  if I try to access the apiKey value immediately after the assignment, the value is null but if I try to access it in an API call once it's published, the correct value is returned.
Here's where I assign the values in the Azure portal. The key is in there, just not visible in this screenshot.

My Program.cs file:
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

CosmosDbConfig.initialize(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "placeholder";
    options.Audience = "placeholder";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
});

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = "placeholder";
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthorizationContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DebugContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<JwtValidator>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<RequestorContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<GetRequestorObjectsFilter>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.AddService<GetRequestorObjectsFilter>();
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    string title = builder.Configuration["VariableName"];
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = title, Version = "v1" });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services
    .AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
    {
        hubOptions.AddFilter<ExceptionHandlingHubFilter>();
    })
    .AddAzureSignalR(hubOptions =>
    {
        hubOptions.ConnectionString = "placeholder";
    });
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policyBuilder =>
{
    policyBuilder
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithOrigins("placeholder");
}));

builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
{
    string accountName = "placeholder";
    string containerName = "placeholder";
    string accountKey = "placeholder";
    string blobServiceEndpoint = $"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net";
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobServiceEndpoint), new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey));
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    return blobContainerClient;
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

LoggerFactoryProvider.LoggerFactory = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMw>();
app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMw>();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseFileServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>($"/{SignalRHubData.hubName}");
});

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

await ProceduresSetup.run();
app.Run();


Please share the screenshot of  Configuration values in portal.

Where you want to retrieve in Program.cs or in API?Also please share your program.cs and api code files.

I don't see any key which u have set.

I posted the Program.cs file. The key is in the portal, I just didn't capture it in the screenshot. I'm trying to get the value in Program.cs.

Ok..will check and let you know

How does variable in your local configuration look?

I use appsettings.json, but don't have any of the keys I use in the portal in this local file. The appsettings.json file has been working for me even in Program.cs (that's what the placeholder strings mostly are). I intend to move them to the portal if I can get it to work so I don't have to save api keys in my code.

Ok..understood..Allow me sometime..will get back to you

Once try this builder.Configuration.GetValue<String>("VariableName");

Unfortunately it returns null. I tried with String and string.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

While deploying the App to Azure App Service, the configurations are picked from the local configurations file.

So even after deployment the API is not using the Environment Variables dynamically.

I can see the title is changing only at the Swagger but not in the API and also when hardcoded, which you have already tried.



AFAIK, the API will not pick the Environment Variables directly.
As an alternative you can check the below workaround.

Create a new configuration file for Production(appsettings.Production.json).

{
  "TitleSwagger": "Production Title"
}


These values are available only for the Production environment.

My Program.cs file:
var EnvName = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;
var newconfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{EnvName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{   
    string title = newconfig["TitleSwagger"]  ?? "Default API Title";
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = title, Version = "v1" });
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton(newconfig);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
{
    x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        x.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
    }
    else
    {
        x.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    }
}
);



If the value is available in appsettings.Production.json file, the API will be created with same name.

OutPut:


The issue I'm having is that I have two APIs in the API management service in the portal, since I'm using deployment slots. When I deploy to one of them, the name must match what is in the portal for it to properly attach to that particular API, otherwise nothing changes in the portal. So I have to manually edit the values whenever I change deployment slots. The only way to not manually do it would be to have an environment variable in each deployed app service that the code could pick from.

Have you tried any other option like GitHub actions and secrets ?

I have not, but may do so in the future.
